# ASP.NET MVC 5.2 Custom Html Helper using LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to create a custom HTML Helper for a `ComplexType`. The helper should insert multiple `<input>` tags with their respective `<label>`s. For instance, the `ComplexType` represents an Address with `City`, `Street` and `HouseNumber` properties. I have encountered a several problems trying to use the built-in functionality of `Label(string)`, `LabelForModel(string)` and `LabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(...)`. Both `Label()` and `LabelForModel()` methods do nothing but output the string I passed as a parameter. For the `LabelFor<>()` I passed in the correct Expression relating to the subproperty of the address but I got an `ArgumentException`, stating that there is no such property in the model as `Street`, for example. But, if I instead use LabelFor directly in the View, I do not have any problems. I get the localized caption for this field.

Here is an excerpt of the code I tried:

```
var htmlHelper2 = new HtmlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext, htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer);
var propertyName = "Address." + propertyInfo.Name;
builder.InnerHtml += htmlHelper2.Label(propertyName);
```

or

```
builder.InnerHtml += htmlHelper2.LabelForModel(propertyName);
```

I tried this as well:

```
var labelForExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>
               (Expression.Property(expr.Body, property), expr.Parameters);
builder.InnerHtml += htmlHelper.LabelFor(labelForExpression);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `HtmlHelper`? You need to get the `ModelMetadata` of the property, loop through `Properties` and create the labels etc (you should not be using `propertyInfo`). Show the signature of your helper.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, ok, probably the right way to go around this one, but to what helper method do I pass the `ModelMetadata`?

Comment: If you want to create HtmlHelper extension methods I suggest you spend some time studying the MVC source code. But the real question is why would you create an extension method for this as opposed to creating an `EditorTemplate` for `Address` and using `@Html.EditorFor()`?